# stderr and stdout of do-release-upgrade

Tags: bash, io-redirection, subshell

Hy. I was trying to redirect stderr and stdout of 'do-release-upgrade' command with the following command,

```
sudo do-release-upgrade >>logfile 2>&1
```

It does only redirect few lines because do-release-update invoke a subshell. So the contents of the subshell is not redirected on that file. So how can I do it?
FYI, I am currently using ubuntu 14.04.01. The command above works fine on 16.04

Comment: The shell is correct; if it isn't working in an older version of Ubuntu, I can only image the issue with with `do-release-upgrade` itself.

Comment: try surrounding the cmd in a a sub-shell, i.e. `( sudo do-release-upgrade ) >>logfile 2>&1`. (Don't have any way to test, and it may be different depending on environments). Good luck.

Comment: tried. but no luck! thanks though.